Clickable circle sectors with svg path
I am designing nested circles for a project; I adapted this answer with svg which fit me best, making gaps and border easy to add to a path. I also tried as in this topic with the skew and border method that does not work well.
I got nested circles with portions which I'm happy for:

However I would like to make the portions clickable but each is being constraint in a div preventing me to access only the shape. I can't make it work.
If my cursor is in the marked zone (see image below), my inner portion is not selectable (which is great) but neither is the outer portion (which should be) because of the overlapping div.

How can I make it work?
My code is pretty much a JS class now but it produces the following html/CSS:
<div id="container">
    <div id="drawing">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="z-index:99;" class="sosa" width="302" height="302">
            <g style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
                <a href="#"><path id="sosa0" d="M 150.99,1 L 151,101 A 50,50, 0,0,1 151,201 L 151,301 A 150,150, 0,0,0, 150.99,1" style="fill:hsl(270, 80%, 55%)"></path></a>
                <a href="#"><path id="sosa1" d="M 151,301 L 151,201 A 50,50, 0,0,1 150.99,101 L 150.99,1 A 150,150, 0,0,0, 151,301" style="fill:hsl(450, 80%, 55%)"></path></a>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="z-index:98;" class="sosa" width="502" height="502">
            <g style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
                <a href="#"><path id="sosa0" d="M 250.99,1 L 250.99,101 A 150,150, 0,0,1 401,250.99 L 501,250.99 A 250,250, 0,0,0, 250.99,1" style="fill:hsl(270, 80%, 55%)"></path></a>
                <a href="#"><path id="sosa1" d="M 501,250.99 L 401,250.99 A 150,150, 0,0,1 251,401 L 251,501 A 250,250, 0,0,0, 501,250.99" style="fill:hsl(360, 80%, 55%)"></path></a>
                <a href="#"><path id="sosa2" d="M 251,501 L 251,401 A 150,150, 0,0,1 101,251 L 1,251 A 250,250, 0,0,0, 251,501" style="fill:hsl(450, 80%, 55%)"></path></a>
                <a href="#"><path id="sosa3" d="M 1,251 L 101,251 A 150,150, 0,0,1 250.99,101 L 250.99,1 A 250,250, 0,0,0, 1,251" style="fill:hsl(540, 80%, 55%)"></path></a>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

I nest the circles by centering them, stacking them with position: absolute; and making the inner circle the size of the last outer circle.
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

#drawing {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.sosa {
    position: absolute;
}


Not sure I would use overlapping circles here. Why not just use a path for each section? Then you just have a single SVG with multiple paths.

Luckily, we're talking about circles, so all you need to do is make the svg circular using border-radius property.


document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    alert("clicked")
  })
})
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#drawing {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sosa {
  position: absolute;
}

.sosa #sosa0:hover {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  fill: rgba(255, 0, 255, 1);
}

#sosa0 {
  fill: hsl(270, 80%, 55%);
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
<div id="container">
  <div id="drawing">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="z-index:99;" class="sosa" width="302" height="302">
            <g style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
                <a href="#"><path id="sosa0" d="M 150.99,1 L 151,101 A 50,50, 0,0,1 151,201 L 151,301 A 150,150, 0,0,0, 150.99,1" style=""></path></a>
                <a href="#"><path id="sosa1" d="M 151,301 L 151,201 A 50,50, 0,0,1 150.99,101 L 150.99,1 A 150,150, 0,0,0, 151,301" style="fill:hsl(450, 80%, 55%)"></path></a>
            </g>
        </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="z-index:98;" class="sosa" width="502" height="502">
            <g style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
                <a href="#"><path id="sosa0" d="M 250.99,1 L 250.99,101 A 150,150, 0,0,1 401,250.99 L 501,250.99 A 250,250, 0,0,0, 250.99,1" style=""></path></a>
                <a href="#"><path id="sosa1" d="M 501,250.99 L 401,250.99 A 150,150, 0,0,1 251,401 L 251,501 A 250,250, 0,0,0, 501,250.99" style="fill:hsl(360, 80%, 55%)"></path></a>
                <a href="#"><path id="sosa2" d="M 251,501 L 251,401 A 150,150, 0,0,1 101,251 L 1,251 A 250,250, 0,0,0, 251,501" style="fill:hsl(450, 80%, 55%)"></path></a>
                <a href="#"><path id="sosa3" d="M 1,251 L 101,251 A 150,150, 0,0,1 250.99,101 L 250.99,1 A 250,250, 0,0,0, 1,251" style="fill:hsl(540, 80%, 55%)"></path></a>
            </g>
        </svg>
  </div>
</div>




very nice it's perfect thank you! btw if it were a more complex shape how could I have achived the same result ?

you can make polygons and other shapes using the css clip-path property

If you would like to use circle strokes instead of the paths, you can do something like this where the border between the colors are made of black lines and circles.


<svg viewBox="0 0 700 700" width="300" fill="none" stroke-width="100">
  <g transform="translate(350 350) rotate(-90)">
    <a href="#1">
      <circle r="100" stroke="Purple" stroke-dasharray="40 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(0)" />
    </a>
    <a href="#2">
      <circle r="100" stroke="Lime" stroke-dasharray="40 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(180)" />
    </a>
    
    <a href="#3">
      <circle r="200" stroke="DarkViolet" stroke-dasharray="20 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(0)" />
    </a>
    <a href="#4">
      <circle r="200" stroke="Tomato" stroke-dasharray="20 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(90)" />
    </a>
    <a href="#5">
      <circle r="200" stroke="LawnGreen" stroke-dasharray="20 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(180)" />
    </a>
    <a href="#6">
      <circle r="200" stroke="SkyBlue" stroke-dasharray="20 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(270)" />
    </a>
    
    <a href="#7">
      <circle r="300" stroke="MediumPurple" stroke-dasharray="10 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(0)" />
    </a>
    <a href="#8">
      <circle r="300" stroke="Violet" stroke-dasharray="10 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(45)" />
    </a>
    <a href="#9">
      <circle r="300" stroke="Coral" stroke-dasharray="10 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(90)" />
    </a>
    <a href="#10">
      <circle r="300" stroke="DarkOrange" stroke-dasharray="10 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(135)" />
    </a>
    <a href="#11">
      <circle r="300" stroke="GreenYellow" stroke-dasharray="10 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(180)" />
    </a>
    <a href="#12">
      <circle r="300" stroke="PaleGreen" stroke-dasharray="10 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(225)" />
    </a>
    <a href="#13">
      <circle r="300" stroke="LightSkyBlue" stroke-dasharray="10 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(270)" />
    </a>
    <a href="#14">
      <circle r="300" stroke="PowderBlue" stroke-dasharray="10 80"
        pathLength="80" transform="rotate(315)" />
    </a>
    <g stroke="black" stroke-width="2">
      <circle r="349" />
      <circle r="249" />
      <circle r="149" />
      <circle r="49" />
      <line id="l1" x1="50" y1="-1" x2="150" y2="-1" />
      <use href="#l1" transform="rotate(180)" />
      <use href="#l1" transform="translate(100)" />
      <use href="#l1" transform="rotate(90) translate(100)" />
      <use href="#l1" transform="rotate(180) translate(100)" />
      <use href="#l1" transform="rotate(270) translate(100)" />
      <use href="#l1" transform="rotate(0) translate(200)" />
      <use href="#l1" transform="rotate(45) translate(200)" />
      <use href="#l1" transform="rotate(90) translate(200)" />
      <use href="#l1" transform="rotate(135) translate(200)" />
      <use href="#l1" transform="rotate(180) translate(200)" />
      <use href="#l1" transform="rotate(225) translate(200)" />
      <use href="#l1" transform="rotate(270) translate(200)" />
      <use href="#l1" transform="rotate(315) translate(200)" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>




As suggested by Paulie_D you may also try to keep all donut chart segments in a single SVG.
Extend generator script
In the long run it is probably easier to extend your pie generator function to create multiple "donut-groups". This way all linked segments have a perfectly clipped link hit-box by default.
Besides you can ensure unique IDs and you can also load your chart in one chunk (e.g as an <img> element – OK links won't work but maybe interesting for file exports or previews).
Here's an extended version based on Carsten Massmann's script


// Define piechart data
let data = {
  gap: 5,
  groups: [
    {
      //starting angle per group
      ang1: 0,
      ri: 150,
      ro: 250,
      segments: [
        {
        val:66.666,
        link:'#link1'
        }, 
        {
        val:33.333,
        link:'#link6'
        }, 
      ]
    },
    {
      ang1: 45,
      ri: 50,
      ro: 140,
      segments: [
        {
        val:25,
        link:'#link1'
        }, 
        {
        val:25,
        link:'#link2'
        }, 
        {
        val:25,
        link:'#link3'
        }, 
        {
        val:25,
        link:'#link4'
        }, 
      ]
    },
  ]
};

let svg = createPieChart(data)
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", svg);


function createPieChart(data) {
  let svgOut = "";
  let { groups, gap } = data;
  
  //max radius
  let rMax = Math.max(...groups.map(val=>{return val.ro}))
  let cx=rMax;
  let cy=cx
  let width = rMax*2
  let height = rMax*2

  const pt = (r, ang, mns = -1, decimals=2) => {
    const rad = Math.PI / 180;
    const a = (ang - 90) * rad - mns * Math.asin(gap / r);
    return (
      `${+(cx + r * Math.cos(a)).toFixed(decimals)} ${+(cy + r * Math.sin(a)).toFixed(decimals)}`
    );
  };

  groups.forEach((group, i) => {
    let {segments, ang1, ri, ro} = group;
    const segmentValues = segments.map(seg=>{return seg.val})
    const a360 = 360 / segmentValues.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    
    // group segment groups in svg
    svgOut += `<g class="group group_${i}">`;

    segments.forEach((seg, s) => {
      const dang = seg.val * a360; // Delta angle
      const laf = dang > 180 ? 1 : 0; // Large Arc Flag
      const ang2 = ang1 + dang; // Second angle
      const link = seg.link

      svgOut += link ? `<a href="${link}">` : '';
      svgOut += link ? `<title>segment_${i}_${s}</title>` : '';
      
      // add segment path
      svgOut += 
        `<path id="segment_${i}_${s}" class="segment segment_${s}" 
        d="M${pt(ro, ang1)} L${pt( ri, ang1)} A ${ri} ${ri} 0 ${laf} 1 ${pt(ri, ang2, 1)} 
        L${pt(ro, ang2, 1)} A${ro} ${ro} 0 ${laf} 0 ${pt(ro, ang1)}" 
        fill="hsl(${Math.floor(ang1)},80%,55%)" />\n`;
      
      svgOut += link ? `</a>` : '';
      
      //update angle
      ang1 = ang2;
    });
    svgOut += `</g>`;

  });

    // svg output
    const svg = 
`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="${[0, 0, width, height].join(' ')}" width="${width}" height="${height}">
    ${svgOut}
</svg>`;

  return svg;
}
body{
background:#999;
}

.segment{
stroke:#fff;
stroke-width:2px;
}

.segment:hover{
fill:#ccc
}



Basically we're extending the data object structure to allow grouped segment values for each donut. We're adding an outer loop to first check these groups and generate segment paths for each value in the group segment array.
